# 「noun」は、「noun」でも代用かのうです。 - What is the role of でも here？

Tags: particles, particle-で, particle-も, particle-でも

For example if you have the sentence "ストッキングは、靴下でも代用かのうです。"
Is でも a single word or is it the で-particle followed by the も-particle? If the latter one is the case, then も can be left off right?

Answer (score 2):

Basically it's で ("with") followed by も ("even/also"), but the nuance added by this type of も is not large. See: [Nuance between でいい and でもいい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15091/5010)

靴下**で**代用可能です is "substitutable **with** socks", and 靴下**でも**代用可能です is a little closer to "substitutable **also with** socks", but in a sentence like this, も is unimportant and optional. It's okay to ignore も and just translate it simply like "you can use socks instead".

Answer (score 0):

> ストッキングは、靴下でも代用かのうです

I would say that this も means "or the like". This meaning comes from the all-mighty "also". で is the particle that marks what thing you replace with.

> You can replace ストッキング with 靴下 or the like.

I mean by omitting も, you could be implying that you can **only** replace it in that particular way.

For example

> テープが無くなったので、のりで代用する。
> Tape has run out so we will substitute it with glue. -> We run out of tape, so we will use glue instead.

Note that you  will use glue and nothing else.

So, it's pretty neat that they included も in the answer because it implies that you may replace it with other words but also 靴下 in particular.